# Receiving AJAX response from Google Datastore

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to learn jQuery via the documentation without success. I cant figure out how to GET the server's response to my POST. Ive been searching the forum for answers, and adapting my code, but nothing has worked so far.

- The post is successful.
- I'm using chrome dev tool to debug- the response window is empty.
- The server is suppose to send html via Jinja. No errors from the
  console.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head on this for hours.

```
            // SUBMIT
            $('#task-form').submit(function(){
                var id = $('.task-focus-home').attr('id');
                $("input[name='parent-key']").val(id);
                $.ajax( '/sub-task.html', {
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType : 'html',
                    data : $( "#task-form" ).serialize(), 
                    success : function(data) {
                        $('#sub-task').html(data); 
                    }
                });
            });
```

edit: my basic problem is that I dont know how to execute the get method using parameters.

Comment: Wait, you're sending data to an HTML page? I'd at least expect a Server-side scripting language... then again I haven't worked with Google Datastorage yet.

Comment: Do you have any other means of checking what or even if your server is sending something?

Comment: I got this to work. In the process of doing so though, I realized that I need to get a better understanding of the api according to what Im trying to accomplish. Need to rethink my approach. Thanks for your replies. Its nice to know help does exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
success is being deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. You may want to try "done", "fail" or "always" callbacks, as in the example below (excerpt from JQuery doc):

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(data) {
    alert( "success with data: " + data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second complete" );
});
```